# Solver find a feasible solution via dialog box but can not find a solution via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, solver

The solver is able to find a solution if I execute the solver via the data tab but I can not get the VBA code to find a solution. I always get a return value of 5.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Calculations").Range("F3") = Txt_UTOR.Text
Sheets("Calculations").Range("G3") = TEXT_TOREH.Text
Sheets("Calculations").Range("H3") = TEXT_UHSR.Text
Sheets("Calculations").Range("I3") = TEXT_HSREH.Text
Sheets("Calculations").Range("S3") = Capacity_Text.Text

Worksheets("Calculations").Calculate

SolverOK SetCell:=Sheets("Calculations").Range("Q3"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.0286, ByChange:=Sheets("Calculations").Range("C3")
SolverSolve

PERCENT_LEFT_TEXT.Text = Sheets("Calculations").Range("T3")
CAPACITY_LEFT_TEXT.Text = Sheets("Calculations").Range("U3")

End Sub
```

Comment: In order for us to reproduce the problem, can you share the values of the cells you are using?

Comment: @BigBen It is about 8000 points of data, is there a way for me to share the sheet?

Comment: Add a copy of the data on Google Sheets maybe and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is, but I have been able to come up with a temporary solution. Simply put the command button on the same sheet as the solver is working.